# How to import a certain image and get the exact path (imagename) after build in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

I am using the next-seo package. How can I import an image and get the correct imagename/url in the image section?

```
<NextSeo
  title="a certain title"
  description="a certain description"
  canonical="https://www.d"
  openGraph={{
    url: "https://www.tandartsenpraktijk-herckenrode.be",
    title: "a certain title",
    description: "a certain description",
    images: [
      {
        url: "?????",
      },
    ],
    site_name: "A certain name",
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Where does the image come from? Where is it hosted?

Comment: I deploy on Vercel... Everything gets build automatically when the main branch gets a new commit. Seems lik I am unable to upload a static image on Vercel. Or should I add that image in a specific place like the favicon?

Comment: You can move the image file to the `public` folder.

Comment: So it will be uploaded in the root with the same name?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thx man it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the image in the public folder was the correct answer...